# Why do the definitions of \quad, etc. have \relax in them?

Tags: tex-core, expansion, plain-tex

Plain Tex defines `\quad` so:

```
\def\quad{\hskip1em\relax}
```

Why is the `\relax` there?  It's usually used as a token that can't be expanded, serving as a "do nothing" operation  after macro expansion is finished.  But that use seems redundant, because it follows a command, namely `\hskip`.

The macro is defined alongside `\enskip` and `\qquad` in [plain.tex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/plain/base/plain.tex), and in Latex in `ltspace.dtx`.

An idle question, but I guess the reason for it will be worth knowing.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

So that \quad doesn't eat following text while assembling the argument of \hskip:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\def\quad{\hskip1em\relax}

\quad plus 1em text

\def\quad{\hskip1em}

\quad plus 1em text
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a general feature of TeX skips: see also how LaTeX defines a number of wrappers so that 'escape' does not take place.

Comment: Thank you.  I guess this highlights the risks associated with designing robust macros.

Comment: Fischer's explanation above can also be seen on the dangerous bend in pg. 71 of Knuth's The TeXbook.